# Compare sources in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Very often I encounter situation where I need to see or manually compare two eclipse sources. It can be a situation when I extending some class and looking at current implementation of superclass and writing similar implementation in subclass. Here are solutions come in mind with time:

- Just copy prototype class in another file and edit it in place with commenting/uncommenting. This solution seems a bit dirty to me and causes hidden "copy-paste" bugs.
- Open prototype class in another editor and make it "always visible". It's a tricky.
- Have state where prototype and actual classes accesed sequentially, so we can using Back-Forward hotkeys `ALT+LEFT` and `ALT+RIGHT` to switch between them, but the problem left - we have only one active screen at time.

Is there a more clever way to get functionality that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [@Nos explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348207/930271) the more accurate solution, but if you need to have two active editors at the same time... You only need to open the both files, and then "detach" one of the tabs, or move it to another editor.

To move a tab to other editor window, you only need to click on the [tab title and drag it to another position](http://www.tipstank.com/2010/06/03/open-multiple-editors-and-split-windows-in-eclipse/). It will automatically created another editor window.

Answer (score 1):

you can click on source file tab and right click-> then select new editor. you will get duplicate tab there. after that click on that and drag to any direction and you will get two different frames for file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of Eclipse you are using but in general you just select the two files (using the ctrl-key + mouse) you wish to compare, then right click on one of the selected files, go to "Compare with" sub-menu and select 'Each Other'?

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. It executes `Java Compare` that `diff` utility functionality. I want just two active editors.